# Is there a .net analogue to the Boost libraries?

Tags: .net, boost

As per the title.

I think .Net libraries would definitely benifit from some sort of community development; perhaps something like the Java Community Process. This is where an analogue would be very helpful.

EDIT: I think people are believing that I need to use some libraries. That's not what I'm talking about. I mean something like a formal (or near-formal) process to add new libraries to the BCL.

Comment: What kinds of things would you like to see?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that there is is Micorosft's [Connect site](http://connect.microsoft.com/), which is a formal feedback site that the internal teams really do use and respond to. You can also vote on feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

Wintellect was working on a project called ".NET Power Collections" for a long time.  One of the people on it used to work on the C# compiler.  It seems like it stalled, but I'm not sure.

It's now on codeplex: http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections

Comment: Some other very helpful collection classes that go beyond the classes supplied in the .NET Framework van be found at the C5 Collections at [http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Boost libraries,

but there are a large number of open source .NET projects on http://codeplex.com
also check out the "open source" home at Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/default.aspx

I'm thinking that codeplex is more what you are looking for though...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the Boost libraries, but the obvious open source/community implementation of the .NET FCL and CLR would be the [Mono project](http://mono-project.com/Contributing) founded by Miguel De icaza.

Wintellect (Jeffrey Richter) also provide a [Power Threading](http://www.wintellect.com/Resources.aspx) library, unfortunately it appears it is not open source.

Answer (score 0):

after reading this [Boost Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149268/boost-library)
I would say that my last answer isn't really what you are looking for..

but the closest that you would probably come are some of the open source projects that the ASP.NET team is working on. Specifically the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit (http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit) and the ASP.NET MVC project (http://www.asp.net/mvc/) and some of the Silverlight controls and projects(http://www.codeplex.com/sdlsdk and http://silverlightcontrib.org/)

You may also want to check out some of the work being done on the Mono Project (http://www.mono-project.com) ... that's the open source implementation of .NET

Answer (score 0):

> I mean something like a formal (or near-formal) process to add new libraries to the BCL.

There doesn't appear to be anything like that.  If you have ideas about what you'd like to see in the BCL, I'd suggest that you start by posting them on the Microsoft forums.  The better developed your proposal is, the more likely it is to have an impact.

Good luck.