# C++ fastest cin for reading stdin?

Tags: c++, performance

I've profiled a computationally-heavy C++ program on Linux using cachegrind. Surprisingly, it turns out the bottleneck of my program is not in any sorting or computational method ... it's in reading the input.

Here is a screenshot of cachegrind, in case I'm mis-interpreting the profiler results (**see** `scanf()`):

[image: Profiler Results]

I hope I'm right in saying that `scanf()` is taking 80.92% of my running time.

I read input using `cin >> int_variable_here`, like so:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false); // Supposedly makes I/O faster
cin >> NumberOfCities;
cin >> NumberOfOldRoads;
Roads = new Road[NumberOfOldRoads];

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOldRoads; i++)
{
    int cityA, cityB, length;    

    cin >> cityA;
    //scanf("%d", &cityA);    // scanf() and cin are both too slow
    cin >> cityB;
    //scanf("%d", &cityB);
    cin >> length;
    //scanf("%d", &length);

    Roads[i] = Road(cityA, cityB, length);
}
```

If you don't spot any issues with this input reading code, could you please recommend a faster way to read input? I'm thinking of trying `getline()` (working on it while I wait for responses). My guess is getline() may run faster because it has to do less conversion and it parses the stream a less total number of times (just my guess, though I'd have to parse the strings as integers eventually too).

What I mean by "too slow" is, this is part of a larger homework assignment that gets timed out after a certain period of time (I believe it is 90 seconds). I'm pretty confident the bottleneck is here because I purposely commented out a major portion of the rest of my program and it still timed out. I don't know what test cases the instructor runs through my program, but it must be a huge input file. So, what can I use to read input fastest?

The input format is strict: 3 integers separated by one space for each line, for many lines:

Sample Input:

```
7 8 3
7 9 2
8 9 1
0 1 28
0 5 10
1 2 16
```

I need to make a `Road` out of the integers in each line.

Also please not that input is redirected to my program to the standard input (`myprogram < whatever_test_case.txt`). I'm not reading a specific file. I just read from `cin`.

### Update

**Using [Slava's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036951/555547) method:**

Input reading seems to be taking less time, but its still timing out (may not be due to input reading anymore). Slava's method is implemented in the `Road() ctor` (2 down from `main`). So now it takes 22% of the time as opposed to 80%. I'm thinking of optimizing `SortRoadsComparator()` as it's called 26,000,000 times.

[image]

**Comparator Code:**

```
// The complexity is sort of required for the whole min() max(), based off assignment instructions
bool SortRoadsComparator(const Road& a, const Road& b)
{
    if (a.Length > b.Length) 
        return false;

    else if (b.Length > a.Length) 
        return true;

    else
    {
        // Non-determinism case
        return ( (min(a.CityA, a.CityB) < min(b.CityA, b.CityB)) ||
            (
            (min(a.CityA, a.CityB) == min(b.CityA, b.CityB)) && max(a.CityA, a.CityB) < max(b.CityA, b.CityB)                                     
            )
            );
    }
}
```

**Using [enhzflep's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15037439/555547) method**

[image]

#### Considering solved

I'm going to consider this problem solved because the bottleneck is no longer in reading input. Slava's method was the fastest for me.

Comment: In your case `cin` *is* a file. If you want to see whether scanf is really the bottleneck, you should be reading from memory (i.e., read the whole file into memory beforehand, and ignore that in the profile).

Comment: I will try this. I'll use the overload of `getline(cin, string, EOF)` which should read it all at once. I'll split first by `\n` to separate each line, then split each line by ` ` to get each integer. Does this sound efficient?

Comment: 3 millions of numbers to scan? Should be under second. If it hurts use binary format.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I wish I could really verify why this takes more than 3 minutes to run, but I can't (test cases are run on a remote machine).

Comment: You should also notice that `scanf` is taking 80% of the time, and `vfscanf` is taking just as much, which just means that most of the time is spent on I/O.

Comment: I would try to read file line by line first, I bet that will be fast enough.

Comment: @Slava, do you recommend custom string parsing per your answer below, or "normal" string -> int conversion (no idea how this is done, I used to use stringstreams but they *seem* rather monstrous).

Comment: If you just write the `for` loop with three `cin`s (without the `roads[i] = ...` and nothing else in the program, how long does it take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams pretty well know to be very slow. It is not a big surprise though - they need to handle localizations, conditions etc. One possible solution would be to read file line by line by std::getline( std:::cin, str ) and convert string to numbers by something like this:

```
std::vector<int> getNumbers( const std::string &str )
{
   std::vector<int> res;
   int value = 0;
   bool gotValue = false;
   for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ) {
      if( str[i] == ' ' ) {
         if( gotValue ) res.push_back( value );
         value = 0;
         gotValue = false;
         continue;
      }
      value = value * 10 + str[i] - '0';
      gotValue = true;
   }
   if( gotValue ) res.push_back( value );
   return res;
}
```

I did not test this code, wrote it to show the idea. I assume you do not expect to get anything in input but spaces and numbers, so it does not validate the input.

To optimize sorting first of all you should check if you really need to sort whole sequence. For comparator I would write methods getMin() getMax() and store that values in object (not to calculate them all the time):

```
bool SortRoadsComparator(const Road& a, const Road& b)
{
    if( a.Length != b.Length ) return a.Length < b.length;
    if( a.getMin() != b.getMin() ) return a.getMin() < b.getMin();
    return a.getMax() < b.getMax();
}
```

if I understood how you current comparator works correctly.

Comment: Is this custom method of parsing a string actually faster than splitting a string and converting it to an int (not even sure how that conversion is done though)?

Comment: Wait, why not just use `atoi()`? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023519/convert-a-string-to-int).

Comment: you can compare it, i think this should be fast. first of all it is simple. second - it scans string only once for splitting and converting. anyway it will be faster than std::cin.

Comment: @Jason: strtol maybe, but never use atoi, because the latter makes error checking too easy to ignore and too difficult to implement.

Comment: to use atoi you need to split string into numbers which is scan. and atoi is not the fastest function in the world either. But in your case i do not think you be able to detect the difference, you can use atoi or strtol if it is easier for you.

Comment: Are you sure you need to sort whole sequence?

Comment: In `SortRoadsComparator()`, where you see `a.CityA`, where I use it as `min(a.CityA, b.CityB)` ..etc, `CityA` and `CityB` are actually `int` types, so all the `min` and `max` should be O(`1`) (just a lot of comparisons).

Comment: Can you try my variant and see if it effects anything?

Comment: Hi Slava, it turns out I was doing O(n^3) access time in one section of a code. One for loop, one nested for loop, and one LinkedList.Get(n). I made an array out of that LinkedList to get O(1) access time. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

As Slava says, streams (i.e cin) are absolute pigs in terms of performance (and executable file size)

Consider the following two approaches:

```
start = clock();
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false); // Supposedly makes I/O faster
cin >> NumberOfCities >> NumberOfOldRoads;
Roads = new Road[NumberOfOldRoads];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOldRoads; i++)
{
    int cityA, cityB, length;
    cin >> cityA >> cityB >> length;
    Roads[i] = Road(cityA, cityB, length);
}
stop = clock();
printf ("time: %d\n", stop-start);
```

and

```
start = clock();
fp = stdin;
fscanf(fp, "%d\n%d\n", &NumberOfCities, &NumberOfOldRoads);
Roads = new Road[NumberOfOldRoads];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOldRoads; i++)
{
    int cityA, cityB, length;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d\n", &cityA, &cityB, &length);
    Roads[i] = Road(cityA, cityB, length);
}
stop = clock();
printf ("time: %d\n", stop-start);
```

Running each way 5 times (with an input file of 1,000,000 entries + the first 2 'control' lines) gives us these results:

1. Using cin ***without*** the direction to not sync with stdio
   8291, 8501, 8720, 8918, 7164 (avg 8318.3)
2. Using cin ***with*** the direction to not sync with stdio
   4875, 4674, 4921, 4782, 5171 (avg 4884.6)
3. Using fscanf
   1681, 1676, 1536, 1644, 1675 (avg 1642.4)

So, clearly, one can see that the sync_with_stdio(false) direction does help. One can also see that fscanf beats the pants off each approach with cin. In fact, the fscanf approach is nearly ***3 times faster*** than the better of the cin approaches and a whopping ***5 times faster*** than cin when not told to avoid syncing with stdio.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it got slower? Relatively 42% of the program's total running time is spent versus the 22% on Slava's method.

Comment: @Jason -  Hmm. I didn't try Slava's code - just stuck with what I'm familiar with. Looks like I've something new to acquaint myself with. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for writing that though. How I tested it was pretty much exactly as you'd posted it. I confirmed that it does work, it just doesn't seem to be faster *in my application*. It really could mean that yours is faster in most circumstances and my circumstance is odd (or oddly approached). Your benchmarks mean a lot more than my circumstantial graph. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course my code should be faster. It does not mean it is better though. On one side iostream, sscanf, strtol etc are more universal solutions, on another side they have to check their input. As I mentioned if you are sure that input is correct and only contains positive integers then my function will work faster as it is highly specialized for this particular case and does not validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
inline void S( int x ) {
x=0;
while((ch<'0' || ch>'9') && ch!='-' && ch!=EOF) ch=getchar_unlocked();
if (ch=='-')
sign=-1 , ch=getchar_unlocked();
    else
sign=1;
do
x = (x<<3) + (x<<1) + ch-'0';
while((ch=getchar_unlocked())>='0' && ch<='9');
x*=sign;
}
```

you can use this function for any type of number input, just change the paramater type.
This will run pretty faster than std scanf.

If you want to save more time best thing will be to use fread() and fwrite() but in that case you have to manipulate the input by yourself.
To save time you should use fread() to read a large chunk of data from standard input stream in one call.That will decrease the number of I/O calls hence you will see a large difference in time.